# How to limit consuming sequence with Reactive?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive, reactive-programming

We have an application, wherein we have a materialized array of items which we are going to process through a Reactive pipeline. It looks a little like this

```
EventLoopScheduler eventLoop = new EventLoopScheduler();
IScheduler concurrency = new TaskPoolScheduler(
    new TaskFactory(
        new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(threadCount)));
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, itemCount);

// 1. transform on single thread
IConnectableObservable<byte[]> source = 
    numbers.Select(Transform).ToObservable(eventLoop).Publish();

// 2. naive parallelization, restricts parallelization to Work 
// only; chunk up sequence into smaller sequences and process
// in parallel, merging results
IObservable<int> final = source.
    Buffer(10).
    Select(
        batch =>
        batch.
        ToObservable(concurrency).
        Buffer(10).
        Select(
            concurrentBatch =>
            concurrentBatch.
            Select(Work).
            ToArray().
            ToObservable(eventLoop)).
        Merge()).
    Merge();

final.Subscribe();

source.Connect();
Await(final).Wait();
```

If you are really curious to play with this, the stand-in methods look like

```
private async static Task Await(IObservable<int> final)
{
    await final.LastOrDefaultAsync();
}

private static byte[] Transform(int number)
{
    if (number == itemCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("numbers exhausted.");
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bloat, 0, buffer, 0, bloat.Length);
    return buffer;
}

private static int Work(byte[] buffer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("t {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    return 1;
}
```

A little explanation. `Range(1, itemCount)` simulates raw inputs, materialized from a data-source. `Transform` simulates an enrichment process each input must go through, and results in a larger memory footprint. `Work` is a "lengthy" process which operates on the transformed input.

Ideally, we want to minimize the number of transformed inputs held concurrently by the system, while maximizing throughput by parallelizing `Work`. The number of transformed inputs in memory should be batch size (`10` above) times concurrent work threads (`threadCount`).

So for 5 threads, we should retain 50 `Transform` items at any given time; and if, as here, the transform is a 1MB byte buffer, then we would expect memory consumption to be at about 50MB throughout the run.

What I find is quite different. Namely that Reactive is eagerly consuming all `numbers`, and `Transform` them up front (as evidenced by `numbers exhausted.` message), resulting in a massive memory spike up front (@1GB for 1000 `itemCount`).

**My basic question is:** Is there a way to achieve what I need (ie minimized consumption, throttled by multi-threaded batching)?

**UPDATE:** sorry for reversal James; at first, i did not think paulpdaniels and Enigmativity's composition of `Work(Transform)` applied (this has to do with the nature of our actual implementation, which is more complex than the simple scenario provided above), however, after some further experimentation, i may be able to apply the same principles: ie defer Transform until batch executes.

Comment: It appears that you have a problem, and have decided on Rx as part of the solution. Any reason for this? This seems to scream TPL/PLinq to me. See http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#Could

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have made a couple of mistakes with your code that throws off all of your conclusions.

First up, you've done this:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, itemCount);
```

You've used `Enumerable.Range` which means that when you call `numbers.Select(Transform)` you are going to burn through all of the `numbers` as fast as a single thread can take it. Rx hasn't even had a chance to do any work because up till this point your pipeline is entirely enumerable.

The next issue is in your subscriptions:

```
final.Subscribe();

source.Connect();
Await(final).Wait();
```

Because you call `final.Subscribe()` & `Await(final).Wait();` you are creating two separate subscriptions to the `final` observable.

Since there is a `source.Connect()` in the middle the second subscription may be missing out on values.

So, let's try to remove all of the cruft that's going on here and see if we can work things out.

If you go down to this:

```
IObservable<int> final =
    Observable
        .Range(1, itemCount)
        .Select(n => Transform(n))
        .Select(bs => Work(bs));
```

Things work well. The numbers get exhausted right at the end, and processing 20 items on my machine takes about 1 second.

But this is processing everything in sequence. And the `Work` step provides back-pressure on `Transform` to slow down the speed at which it consumes the numbers.

Let's add concurrency.

```
IObservable<int> final =
    Observable
        .Range(1, itemCount)
        .Select(n => Transform(n))
        .SelectMany(bs => Observable.Start(() => Work(bs)));
```

This processes 20 items in 0.284 seconds, and the numbers exhaust themselves after 5 items are processed. There is no longer any back-pressure on the numbers. Basically the scheduler is handing all of the work to the `Observable.Start` so it is ready for the next number immediately.

Let's reduce the concurrency.

```
IObservable<int> final =
    Observable
        .Range(1, itemCount)
        .Select(n => Transform(n))
        .SelectMany(bs => Observable.Start(() => Work(bs), concurrency));
```

Now the 20 items get processed in 0.5 seconds. Only two get processed before the numbers are exhausted. This makes sense as we've limited concurrency to two threads. But still there's no back pressure on the consumption of the numbers so they get chewed up pretty quickly.

Having said all of this, I tried to construct a query with the appropriate back pressure, but I couldn't find a way. The crux comes down to the fact that `Transform(...)` performs far faster than `Work(...)` so it completes far more quickly.

So then the obvious move for me was this:

```
IObservable<int> final =
    Observable
        .Range(1, itemCount)
        .SelectMany(n => Observable.Start(() => Work(Transform(n)), concurrency));
```

This doesn't complete the numbers until the end, and it limits processing to two threads. It appears to do the right thing for what you want, except that I've had to do `Work(Transform(...))` together.

Answer (score 6):

The very fact that you want to limit the amount of work you are doing suggests you should be *pulling* data, not having it pushed at you. I would forget using Rx in this scenario, as fundamentally, what you have described is not a reactive application. Also, Rx is best suited processing items serially; it uses sequential event streams.

Why not just keep your data source enumerable, and use [PLinq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx), [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)? All of those sound better suited for your problem.

Comment: I would disagree with you on your point that limiting the amount of work is an indicator that it is not a reactive problem. There are several operators that serve purpose of limiting data flow and it is certainly a common enough problem.

Comment: Well I have to disagree right back! Such operators are aimed at sampling data, dropping or aggregating information. In many cases these are used to stay reactive in the face of otherwise overwhelming data rates. I have come across this misuse of Rx many times; you can play with the operators to make it work, but fundamentally its not the right tool for a job like this. It *may* be appropriate to create an Rx stream of the results though, but that depends on context not provided.

Comment: Rx is primarily a way to query an observable sequence of events. What the OP has here is a set of data at rest that they want to process in a parallel manner (I assume for maximum throughput). In this case, I completely agree with @JamesWorld, this is a problem best suited for TPL/PLinq

Comment: I am in agreement that PLinq or Parallel.ForEach are likely better options in this case, but is that not because of the nature of the source rather than the nature of the operations? If the source were actually a WebSocket that was firing events in bursts would you still say it is not a Rx application?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely because of the nature of the source - I should have made that clearer (thanks @LeeCampbell, as I think your comment clarified this point superbly). However, I would go further and say that any problem that introduces sustained back-pressure is a strong indication that Rx is not appropriate - and equally any solution that constrains throughput of an Rx pipeline leading to sustained build-up of back-pressure also indicates that Rx is not appropriate. Altogether, as elegant as Enigmativity's currently accepted answer is, I worry that it will drive people down the wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

As @JamesWorld said it may very well be that you want to use PLinq to perform this task, it really depends on if you are actually *reacting* to data in your real scenario or just iterating through it.

If you choose to go the Reactive route you can use `Merge` to control the level of parallelization occurring:

```
var source = numbers
  .Select(n => 
          Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => Work(Transform(n)), concurrency)))
  //Maximum concurrency
  .Merge(10)
  //Schedule all the output back onto the event loop scheduler
  .ObserveOn(eventLoop);
```

The above code will consume all the numbers first (sorry no way to avoid that), however, by wrapping the processing in a `Defer` and following it up with a `Merge` that limits parallelization, only `x` number of items can be in flight at a time. `Start()` takes a scheduler as the second argument which it uses to execute to the provided method. Finally, Since you are basically just pushing the values of `Transform` into `Work` I composed them within the `Start` method.

As a side note, you can `await` an `Observable` and it will be equivalent to the code you have, i.e:

```
await source; //== await source.LastAsync();
```